# Can't get data from deserialized Json string

Tags: c#, json, api, serialization, arraylist

I am really confused as to why I can't access any data that I have deserialized from `Json` string. When I step through the process I can see that the data is there, I just can't access it.

I am placing the data into `Dictionary<string, object>`, it's `Count` is 2. It contains `object{object[]}` (which I read as an `ArrayList` of `objects`?), and an `object` with response information.

I'm not too fussed about the response information I need to access the objects in the `ArrayList`. I'm having no such luck, my code is below:

`var output = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());`

I have tried to get just the `ArrayList` using `output["List"]` (List is the objects key) and can still see all of the objects inside but still can't access them. It's probably a simple fix, it always is, but I have been staring at this problem all day and just can't make sense of it so could do with another pair of eyes.

Thanks

EDIT

The Json string is in the following format:

`{"List":[{"Id":1,"intProperty":2,"boolProperty":false},{"Id":2,"intProperty":3,"boolProperty":false},{"Id":4,"intProperty":5,"boolProperty":false}],"ResponseInformation":{Other info here}}`

Comment: Can you show the JSON string you're working with?

Comment: Have done now, realized after I posted.. Have took the data out but that doesn't really matter I guess

Comment: Have you tried deserializing into a `Dictionary<string, object[]>` instead?

Comment: i have tried `Dictionary<string[], object>` but not that way round... I will try...

Comment: `InnerException {"No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.Object[]'."} System.Exception {System.MissingMethodException}` nope :(

Comment: I have built a class with them three parameters and have tried numerous examples I have found for that but no such luck there either

Comment: Hmm, I was able to get it to work with your example. I was also able to create a class with those three properpty namees and it worked fine

Comment: Typical! What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: I left off the response info part which is included in the Json string could that be the reason?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59370/discussion-between-andrew-whitaker-and-holly-marie-batchelor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out in just two lines!!

`var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;`

`IList<Currency> output = new JsonSerializer().Deserialize<IList<Currency>>(new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json)));`

Answer (score 0):

Deserialize it into a class:

```
public class ListClass
{
    public int Id;
    public int IntProperty;
    public bool boolProperty;
}
```

and then

```
var output = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, ListClass>>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

And that should work!

Comment: Too bad...but anyway, at least this helped _me_. Haha! Thanks for your question! It was a learning experience for me too.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a long winded way of getting the information I need, If anyone can see a way to condense the code I'm open to suggestions :)
First I created my Currency class

```
public class Currency
{
    public int CurrencyId { get; set; }
    public int GlobalCurrencyId { get; set; }
    public bool Archived { get; set; }
}
```

Next I deserialized my Json as I did in my question

`var output = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());`

Next is the long winded bit; I used a foreach statement to get each element of my `output` variable. It was then made clear that the data inside was an array of dictionary objects so I created a list of Currency class objects:

```
var currencyObject = output["List"];

List<Currency> currencyList = new List<Currency>();
Currency item;

ArrayList myList = currencyObject as ArrayList;
foreach (object element in myList)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> L1 = element as Dictionary<string, object>;

    item = new Currency();
    item.CurrencyId = Convert.ToInt32(L1["CurrencyId"]);
    item.GlobalCurrencyId = Convert.ToInt32(L1["GlobalCurrencyId"]);
    item.Archived = Convert.ToBoolean(L1["Archived"]);

    currencyList.Add(item);
}
```